# Spring Boot auto configuration for datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I try to create Spring Boot app with Hibernate 5 and Postgres 9. Now I have next error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans
```

Though, I have added spring.datasource.* properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
```

My pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.data.version>1.10.6.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1212</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Report:

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

AopAutoConfiguration matched:
- @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy', 'org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect', 'org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice' (OnClassCondition)
- @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.auto=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

AopAutoConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
- @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
- @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)

DataSourceAutoConfiguration#dataSourceInitializer matched:
- @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
- @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.TransactionManagementConfiguration matched:
- @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
...
DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration:
Did not match:
- EmbeddedDataSource did not find embedded database (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseCondition)

DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceConfiguration:
Did not match:
- AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.PooledDataSourceAvailable PooledDataSource did not find supported DataSource; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.ExplicitType @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'type' (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition)

DataSourceAutoConfiguration.TomcatDataSourceJmxConfiguration:
Did not match:
- @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy' (OnClassCondition)

DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.CommonsDbcp2PoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration:
Did not match:
- @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.CommonsDbcpPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration:
Did not match:
- @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration:
Did not match:
- @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.TomcatDataSourcePoolMetadataProviderConfiguration:
Did not match:
- @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource' (OnClassCondition)

DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration:
Did not match:
- @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

Any ideas? In most tutorials it all is very standard and very simple, it seems I miss some little part..

Comment: do you have Mysql connector dependency?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're missing several classes (mostly pool related) on your classpath. The easiest solution is to use the Spring boot starter for JPA, which is:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you do this, you can remove the following dependencies since they're all part of the starter:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The alternative solution is to manually add a pool provider to your classpath, the default of **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** is **tomcat-jdbc** (Hikari for Spring boot 2.x) but you can use any connection pool provider you want that is listed in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database).

Answer (score 12):

well the above solution might worked but in  my case with weblogic 11g above solution could not help me. so attaching this solution so anyone elsestruggling with this problem find it useful.

***solution:***

Adding DataSource bean configuration in component scan classpath will fix this for servlets 2.5 like weblogic 10.3.6(11g) like below

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig{

       @Bean
       public DataSource dataSource(){
          DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
          dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          dataSource.setUrl("your url");
          dataSource.setUsername( "username" );
          dataSource.setPassword( "password" );
          return dataSource;
       }

}
```