# Spring Boot jdbcAuthentication dataSource not loaded error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have been working on spring boot for database authentication aplication. Install MySQL database on localhost. But problem is i can not even run my spring application. I use Eclipse with maven on Windows OS. Files that i created and errors are following:

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired  
    private DataSource dxataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource((DataSource) dxataSource).usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
    }
}
```

Application.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
     }

}
```

HomeComtoller.java:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

  @RestController
  public class HomeController {

   @GetMapping("/")
   public String index() {
       return "OK";
   }
 }
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-authenticating-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
     <parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
     </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!-- tag::security[] --> 
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>        
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>      
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
       </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     </dependencies>
     <!-- end::security[] -->
    <build>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
 </project>
```

My application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=password
```

The error appear while i try to run application (On Eclipse IDE):

```
Field dxataSource in auth.ldap.WebSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType
```

any advice and suggestions will really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: maybe missing? spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741135/spring-boot-auto-configuration-for-datasource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your `pom.xml` file.You have added two of the dependencies outside the  tag and also forgot to mention the version for the dependency called- "**spring-boot-starter-jdbc**".

Try to replace it with the pom file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-authenticating-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- end::security[] -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I changed my pom.xml file and it worked, thank you so much.