# Spring-Boot cannot run in Eclipse and not recognize autowired DataSource

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm trying to run simple API server under control of Spring-boot and have 2 problems: 
1. In Eclipse (Neon.1 Release (4.6.1)) when I try to launch application I get an error about servlet container (watch errors at the end of topic).
2. When I run gradle build and try to run jar I see error about not set DataSource bean.

***UPDATE***: Issue 1 not a big deal, cause other person was able to run project from IDEA perfectly fine and smooth (and it worked). Which is interesting, cause in any case, jar builded by gradle give error listed at the end of topic, about missed datasource, even if you move DataSource from main to @Configuration class. Which mean, that I have problem in Eclipse (my local problem) AND problem with gradle build task.

***UPDATE 2***: Issue resolved by [Spring Boot auto configuration for datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741135/spring-boot-auto-configuration-for-datasource) Still I have no idea why dataSource wasn't able to autowire, but this way even better, cause using approach from link I can get values from properties and switch them using different environments. Thanks all for help.

My code followed: 
Application.java:

```
 package com.my.package;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;

import com.my.package.MvcConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "resource" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MvcConfig.class);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

MvcConfig.java:

```
package com.my.package;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Application.properties:

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/benchmark
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =root
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.6.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version:'1.5.6.RELEASE'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version:'1.5.6.RELEASE') {
exclude(module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty', version:'1.5.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version:'1.5.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.6'

    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version:'2.8.1'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'4.3.11.RELEASE') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version:'4.3.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.interceptor', name: 'javax.interceptor-api', version:'1.+'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.11'
}
```

And here is errors. When I'm trying to launch in eclipse:

```
12:40:08.155:WARN [main]: o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext -
                Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
12:40:08.164:INFO [main]: o.s.b.a.l.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer -


Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
12:40:08.169:ERROR[main]: o.s.boot.SpringApplication -
                Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.my.package.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean.onStartup(ServletRegistrationBean.java:191)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.callInitializers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.doStart(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getJettyEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

When I run jar:

```
12:43:24.707:DEBUG[main]: o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
                                Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.my.package.Application.main(Application.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
12:43:24.707:ERROR[main]: o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
        - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
        - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans
```

I've tried to play with dependencies, with annotations in application.java, but wasn't able to run this. I was thinking about this problem local, but I'm not sure where to look (I was reinstalling Gradle to 3.5 version not way back ago).

Comment: You can change the Tomcat version by setting the "tomcat.version" property:
ext['tomcat.version'] = '7.0.63' //version of Tomcat, and add

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}

Comment: Not worked for me, I'm using jetty and when I switched to tomcat I've got same error from tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by [Spring Boot auto configuration for datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741135/spring-boot-auto-configuration-for-datasource) . Still I have no idea why dataSource wasn't able to autowire, but this way even better, cause using approach from link I can get values from properties and switch them using different environments. Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring beans can't be `Autowired` in the main `Application` class out of box. You should move it down to the components like services/controllers etc.

Comment: I've tried to move it to controller and still have same error. Or do I need to add autowired dataSource to each service (cause I have 7 services  and further there will be more up to 20 services)? And I've previously tried to add it to the MvcConfig

Comment: I just noticed in your  log `Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;` It looks like you need to hunt a dependency issue and exclude 'servlet-api' See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080541/getting-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-addservlet-in-spring-boo

Comment: Tried this, wont help either. I will update main topic with new info right now, which can be very helpful

Comment: @Konstantin Can you provide the directory structure of your app. How do you run your gradle? How did you bild your jar?

Comment: I've updated question