# Spring Boot cannot find DataSource Bean in JUnit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I try to write some unit tests for my Spring Boot application (as of now it is a simple CRUD app for user management only).

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class UserControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserService UserService;
    @MockBean
    private UserTypeService UserTypeService;
    @MockBean
    private UserTrainingService UserTrainingService;
    @MockBean
    private TrainingService trainingService;
    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;
    
    @InjectMocks
    UserController UserController;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    private static final int USER_ID = 1;

    private User User1;
        
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(UserController).build();

        UserType UserType = new UserType();
        UserType.setName("Regular");
        // some further setup steps. Ommited for clarity
    }
        
    @Test
    public void testInitUserDetailsView() throws Exception {        
        mockMvc.perform(get("/users/{id}", User_ID))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("user"))
            .andExpect(view().name("user_details"));
    }
}
```

When I try to run above, I get following error about missing DataSource Bean:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field dataSource in com.example.app.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

I am using `MySQL` server, config is saved in `application.properties` file. What is interesting, application itself works well. Only tests are failing.
I have tried to manually set a `DataSource` in my config class, as described by praveen kumar within:

- [Spring Boot auto configuration for datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741135/spring-boot-auto-configuration-for-datasource).

But the results are the same. Here is my `SecurityConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    private String usersQuery = "SELECT username, password, active FROM users WHERE username=?";
    private String authoritiesQuery = "SELECT u.username, r.name FROM users u INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON(u.id=ur.user_id) INNER JOIN roles r ON(ur.role_id=r.id) WHERE u.username=?";
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(authoritiesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
            
    }
}
```

and `ApplicationConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:ValidationMessages.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    // Custom validation messages from external file
    @Bean
       public MessageSource messageSource() {
          ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
          messageSource.setBasename("classpath:ValidationMessages");
          messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
          return messageSource;
       }
    
    @Bean
     public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(MessageSource messageSource) {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return bean;
     }
        
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
       dataSource.setUsername( "user" );
       dataSource.setPassword( "pass" );
       return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Full failure trace:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-09-16 13:20:54.549  INFO 10168 --- [           main] n.b.o.c.UserControllerTest        : Starting UserControllerTest on DESKTOP-FU0FUI6 with PID 10168 (started by Kamil in E:\Projekty Spring\osp)
2019-09-16 13:20:54.552  INFO 10168 --- [           main] n.b.o.c.UserControllerTest        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-16 13:20:55.791  WARN 10168 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2019-09-16 13:20:55.795  INFO 10168 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-16 13:20:55.819 ERROR 10168 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field dataSource in com.example.myapp.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.

2019-09-16 13:20:55.868 ERROR 10168 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@1e730495] to prepare test instance [com.example.myapp.controller.UserControllerTest@3ae0b770]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:843) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1655) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters remove the first 2 lines of your setup method (that is already being done by Spring). Secondly you are running a `@WebMvcTest` which will only configure the web part of Spring Boot and nothing else. Hence no datasource. If you really want you can add an `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` which will configure an in-memory test db,

Comment: I got rid of the errors by adding `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` and adding H2 dependency to my project - thank you. However, how do I add a data to that embedded database? Is that possible to create objects manually within setup method in my test class?

Comment: OK I switched to test database (local MySQL server but different DB). My tests are running OK, but those which requires a data are failing. For example, when I want to test edit form for single user it cannot find it, while it is in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been resolved by adding `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` annotation to my test class, as adviced by M.Deinum.